# Vigenere Cipher Algorithm In Java - Decrypted Message to Plaintext

Tags: java, algorithm, vigenere

I am currently trying to write the Vigenere Cipher algorithm in Java. I have to change the decrypted message to the plaintext but having trouble. Below is what I have so far.

When I run it, the message is not deciphered properly.
[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VigenereCipher {
        public static void main(String arg[]) {
            String message = "";
            String keyword = "KISWAHILI";
            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a message: ");
            message = sc.nextLine();
            
            char msg[] = message.toCharArray();
            int msgLength = msg.length;
        
            
            char key[] = new char [msgLength];
            char decryptedText[] = new char[msgLength];
            
            for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < msgLength; i++, j++) {
                if(j == keyword.length()) {
                    j = 0;
                }
                key[i] = keyword.charAt(j);
            }
            
            // Decryption Code
            for(int i =0; i < msgLength; i++) {
                decryptedText[i] = (char)(((key[i] + 26) % 26) + 'A');
            }
            System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + message);
            System.out.println("Keyword: " + keyword);
            System.out.println("Plaintext: " + String.valueOf(decryptedText));
        }
}
```

Comment: In your "Decryption code", shouldn't `msg[i]` be involved somehow?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I did add it under the decryption code section, msg[i] + key[i] + 26... but it still didn't work so i took it out. Sorry should have commented that out

Comment: I think you might want something more like `((msg[i] - 'A') + (key[i] - 'A')) % 26 + 'A'`.  Or maybe `((msg[i] - 'A') - (key[i] - 'A')) % 26 + 'A'`, depending on which way the text was originally enciphered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that whitespaces need to be skipped while populating `key` array:

```java
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < msgLength; i++) {
    if (msg[i] == ' ') {
        key[i] = ' ';
    } else {
        key[i] = keyword.charAt(j++ % keyword.length());
    }
}
System.out.println("Key Message:       " + new String(key));
```

Similarly, it needs to be taken into account in the decrypting loop.
And decryption [has to be fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher):
*D<sub>i</sub> = (M<sub>i</sub> - K<sub>i</sub>* + 26 *)* mod 26

```java
for (int i =0; i < msgLength; i++) {
    char c = msg[i];
            
    decryptedText[i] = c == ' ' ? c : (char)(((msg[i] - key[i] + 26) % 26) + 'A');
}
```

Upon applying these changes, the output is as follows:

```
Key Message:       KISW AH ILIKI SW AHILIKIS WAH ILI KISW AHILIKISW AHIL IKIS
Encrypted Message: XQKP IZ IMWEB LK AUVZCXKW PHL VPE RIKD ASOZZSBZI TOIE ESTD
Keyword: KISWAHILI
Plaintext: NIST IS ABOUT TO ANNOUNCE THE NEW HASH ALGORITHM THAT WILL
```

Comment: I just tried it with the whole cyphertext and it only worked up to a certain point. If I have numbers and special characters would the decryption code be a bit different?

Comment: Yes, you need to maintain a sort of alphabet with acceptable characters and then modify modulo arithmetics.